# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.datafx.provider.PublishingTask$1.run(PublishingTask.java:41)

Tags: java, rest, javafx, java-8

Using datafx read json from rest script.
Below is the code

```
    @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
    JsonConverter jsonConvert = new JsonConverter("jsonCase", CaseTable.class);
    RestSource test = RestSourceBuilder.create()
                      .converter(jsonConvert)
                      .host("http://devel.com.au")
                      .path("cgi-bin").path("ssinternalweb-jcgi.sh")
                      .queryParam("Program", "appfx/CaseTest.p")
                      .queryParam("ProcName", "FXRequest")
                      .queryParam("TestParam", "aValue").build();
    ListDataProvider<CaseTable> ldp = ListDataProviderBuilder.create()
            .dataReader(test)
            .build();
    Worker<ObservableList<CaseTable>>retrieve = ldp.retrieve();      
    lvCases.setItems(retrieve.getValue());                                                                                      
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    lvCases.setCellFactory(l -> new CaseTableCell());
    lvCases.getItems().add(new CaseTable(999, "Loading..."));
}
```

When worker start processing the results i get the following error message

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.datafx.provider.PublishingTask$1.run(PublishingTask.java:41)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1175034525.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have but break point in class i am trying to create at that seems to be receiving the correct values.  Only problem not showing on the screen in the listview.

```
private ListView<CaseTable> lvCases;
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate lvCases ?

Comment: you does not have initialised your lvCases ListView

Comment: Your methods are not mentioned anywhere in the stack trace - the problem is probably somewhere else...

Comment: Was wondering if problem with CaseTableCell but that why inserted the loading... object just test no problem there

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/datafx/datafx/issue/9/npe-when-resultlist-not-specified

Comment: Wondering if this exception is because of the jars I am using? I think try download them using maven instead of manually doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in one of my comments should set the result list and will not get this error message.  Was different line that's why thought was not related but turns out to be exactly same problem.
Below is update code that now works.

```
    @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    JsonConverter jsonConvert = new JsonConverter("jsonCase", CaseTable.class);
    RestSource test = RestSourceBuilder.create()
                      .converter(jsonConvert)
                      .host("http://devel.com.au")
                      .path("cgi-bin").path("ssinternalweb-jcgi.sh")
                      .queryParam("Program", "appfx/CaseTest.p")
                      .queryParam("ProcName", "FXRequest")
                      .queryParam("TestParam", "aValue").build();
    lvCases.getItems().removeAll(lvCases.getItems());
    ListDataProvider<CaseTable> ldp = ListDataProviderBuilder.create()
            .dataReader(test)
            .resultList(lvCases.getItems())
            .build();
    Worker<ObservableList<CaseTable>>retrieve = ldp.retrieve();                                                                                         
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    lvCases.setCellFactory(l -> new CaseTableCell());
    lvCases.getItems().add(new CaseTable(999, "Loading..."));
}
```

Refer to this for more details

https://bitbucket.org/datafx/datafx/issue/9/npe-when-resultlist-not-specified